# Как добавить слайд на переход по вкладкам

Tags: java, android

У меня 3 активити. 1 - главная. 2 - это активити вкладок. У главного активити нету Лэйоута.

**Вот код:**

```
    public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    final Resources res = getResources();
    final TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();

    final Intent i1 = new Intent().setClass(this, FirstActivity.class);
    final TabSpec oneSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec("A").setIndicator("Первая")
            .setContent(i1);
    tabHost.addTab(oneSpec);

    final Intent i2 = new Intent().setClass(this, SecondActivity.class);
    final TabSpec twoSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec("B").setIndicator("Вторая")
            .setContent(i2);
    tabHost.addTab(twoSpec);
    tabHost.setCurrentTab(2);
}
```

Переход идет у меня сейчас только когда нажимаешь на вкладки...

**Вопрос: Как сделать так чтобы по слайду переходило?**

Comment: `TabHost` устарел уже года 3 назад, а вы прям как динозавр - им пользуетесь до сих пор. `ViewPager` решает все эти проблемы.

Comment: Мне тогда придется на главный Активити добавить главный Лэйоут...

Comment: и... Не вижу проблемы

Comment: Получается чтобы перейти на ViewPager придется все переделать?